# Group Join between three tables to get the percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by

I have three tables Attendance, Employee, Sector
Employee Table

```
EmiId -Name -SectorId
123     ABC   1
231     BCD   2
125    WER    1
```

Attendance

```
AttId -EmpId -Dt
1      123    12/12/2014 9:00
2      231    12/12/2014 10:00
```

Sector

```
SectorId -SectorName
1          North Sector
2          East Sector
```

my query is

```
  SELECT COUNT(Attendance.Emp_Id) as AttCount,(select COUNT(*) from Employee) as EmpCount
FROM  Employee  INNER JOIN
               Sector ON Employee.SectorId = Sector.SectorId INNER JOIN
               Attendance ON Employee.EmpId = Attendance.EmpId          
               group by Sector.SectorId
```

and i keep getting same number of employees for both instead so the `(select COUNT(*) from Employee)`- EmpCount seems to be incorrect.I keep getting the same number for both the sectors. Although the Attcount seems to work fine.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your desired results with your sample data?

Comment: i am looking for the total attendance for the sector and the employees belonging to each sector (count). It keeps showing same number of employees for both sectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just making select count from the same table - do not expect other results.

Perhaps someone could do it better

```
SELECT COUNT(Attendance.Emp_Id),COUNT(case when Employee.empid=attendance.attid then 1 else 0 end)
    FROM  Employee JOIN Sector ON Employee.SectorId = Sector.SectorId 
                   LEFT JOIN Attendance ON Employee.EmpId = Attendance.Emp_Id          
    group by Sector.SectorId
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need LEFT JOIN with Attendance

```
SELECT COUNT(Attendance.Emp_Id),(select COUNT(*) from Employee)
FROM  Employee JOIN Sector ON Employee.SectorId = Sector.SectorId 
               LEFT JOIN Attendance ON Employee.EmpId = Attendance.EmpId          
group by Sector.SectorId
```